# Create class with 2D easily searched information

Tags: python-2.7, class, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to make somewhat of a pseudo-database of players by creating instances of a Player class for football. So, the information in my Player would have certain values such as

```
self.age
self.height
self.weight, etc.
```

as well as seasonal data, which I would format something like the following:

```
player_year    year     yards    comp_perc    rushing
     X1        2008      400        65           70
     X2        2009      500        35          100
```

Once I have created an instance of each player, I would then pickle everything in order to save it once I have scraped everything. My issue is then that I would like a way of cleanly looking through the tables for each player, such as wanting all 'yards' stats from 'player_year' X2 from each player. Is the cleanest way of doing this a 2d dictionary such as

```
dict['x1']['yards']
```

and if so, how would I be able to read this in neatly row by row. I would also like to mention that 'X1' would need to be created by my code as it is not a part of the scraped data.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you looked at the [Pandas package](http://pandas.pydata.org/)? It seems like a perfect fit to your problem, no need to create custom classes.

Comment: Actually that is wonderful! I had previously been avoiding a dataframe because of the Height, weight and other scalars associated with a player, but I could just make them constant columns

Comment: Or you could store such constant data in a separate table and join them when you need to use/print all data at once. By the way, doesn't weight change through time as well? ;)

Comment: A join at the end is probably easiest, yeah. And it turns out even pro athletes try to keep their weights hidden...